# Create an exe file from a Django project with pyinstaller

Tags: python, django, pyinstaller

I have a problem with generating an .exe file from a Django project using PyInstaller.

My goal is to start the Django development server and open the web browser to the homepage by running the file. For this purpose, I have created a file (start.py) that is supposed to start the server:

```
import os
import time
import webbrowser
from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "django_test.settings")

def run_server():
    execute_from_command_line(["manage.py", "runserver"])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_server()
```

I create the exe file using PyInstaller:

```
pyinstaller start.py --onefile
```

When I run the exe file (`./dist/start`), I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "start.py", line 19, in <module>
    run_server()
  File "start.py", line 16, in run_server
    execute_from_command_line(["manage.py", "runserver"])
  File "django/core/management/__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
  File "django/core/management/__init__.py", line 436, in execute
  File "django/core/management/base.py", line 412, in run_from_argv
  File "django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 74, in execute
  File "django/core/management/base.py", line 458, in execute
  File "django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 111, in handle
  File "django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 118, in run
  File "django/utils/autoreload.py", line 673, in run_with_reloader
  File "PyInstaller/hooks/rthooks/pyi_rth_django.py", line 24, in _restart_with_reloader
  File "django/utils/autoreload.py", line 272, in restart_with_reloader
  File "django/utils/autoreload.py", line 229, in get_child_arguments
IndexError: list index out of range
```

When I run the start.py file, the server can be started without any problems. Does anyone know where the issue might be

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using PyInstaller with Django, you need to add the "--noreload" argument to the command :

```py
def run_server():
    execute_from_command_line(["manage.py", "runserver", "--noreload"])
```

I honestly couldn't explain *why*. This option says, "don't reload if I change the Python code", as specified in the docs. Maybe exe files are not compatible with watching changes.

Comment: Ok, the problem can be solved with this. However, the module can no longer be found. I get the error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '<name_of_the_app>.apps`. Do you know why this error occurs?

Comment: This error could occur for a great number of reasons, unrelated to your original question. Using PyInstaller with Django is really not straight-forward, because Django has a lot of hidden imports, which you may need to point out to PyInstaller. Is the not found module a common library, or one of your apps? What is your hidden imports config for PyInstaller?

Comment: The module that is not found is the app itself `No module named "<name_of_the_app>.apps"`. I've already tried adding them to the app's hidden imports `--hidden-import <name-of-the-app>.apps`. But it didn't work either.

Comment: A hook may do the trick : [check the docs](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/hooks.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I was able to solve the problem by adding different modules to the hidden imports.

Comment: hi @MrT can you tell us how you did it? how did you formulate the different modules for the hidden imports? thank you!